# rplidarNode on raspberi pi, Error health code: 8000802

Tags: raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am working on ROS on Raspberry Pi2.

My problem is that rplidarNode not working on Raspberry Pi.
But give the message : "Error, cannot retreive rplidar health code: 8000802"

What's mean ? I curious about this...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223678/rplidarnode-on-raspberi-pi,-error-health-code:-8000802/) by [Jeesang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25501/jeesang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you check the permission of serial port?

```
ll /dev/ttyUSB*
```

If the permission is not to be read,

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB*
```

After that,you can start to run the sample.
terminal 1:

```
roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch
```

terminal 2:

```
rosrun rplidar_ros rplidarNodeClient
```

And the terminal 2 will show the rplidar scanner's data.

---

Originally posted by [YingHua](https://answers.ros.org/users/24018/yinghua/) with karma: 196 on 2016-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1